# Get checkboxes value from javascript tree using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree

I have created Tree structure using jquery it is so basic tree structure but i am stuck at problem . Any help would be appreciated.

I am not able to get selected checkboxes items.Also this code has small problem , when parent checkbox unchecked but its child still checked how to solve this problem and then get only child which for which its parent is checked.

Here is working code : http://jsfiddle.net/deepshah/2zefx66s/

```
var data = {
id: 0,
title: "root - not displayed",
children: [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Option 1",
    children: [{
        id: 11,
        title: "Option 11",
        children: [{
            id: 111,
            title: "Option 111"
        }, {
            id: 112,
            title: "Option 112"
        }]
    }, {
        id: 12,
        title: "Option 12"
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: "Option 2",
    children: [{
        id: 21,
        title: "Option 21"
    }, {
        id: 22,
        title: "Option 22"
    }]
}, {
    id: 3,
    title: "Option 3",
    children: [{
        id: 0,
        title: "Option 31"
    }, {
        id: 0,
        title: "Option 32"
    }]
}]
};

function addItem(parentUL, branch) {
for (var key in branch.children) {
    var item = branch.children[key];
    $item = $('<li>', {
        id: "item" + item.id
    });
    $item.append($('<input>', {
        type: "checkbox",
        id: "item" + item.id,
        name: "item" + item.id
    }));
    $item.append($('<label>', {
        for: "item" + item.id,
        text: item.title
    }));
    parentUL.append($item);
    if (item.children) {
        var $ul = $('<ul>', {
            style: 'display: none'
        }).appendTo($item);
        $item.append();
        addItem($ul, item);
    }
}
}

$(function () {
addItem($('#root'), data);
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
});
$('label').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').trigger('click');
});
});
```

This is javacript code so far i have created.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2zefx66s/1/

Comment: thanks @dm4web .this gives me check boxes values but please see my updated question and help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

With the following selector you get the checked checkboxes:

```
$(':checkbox:checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2zefx66s/2/

```
$(function () {
    addItem($('#root'), data);
    $(':checkbox').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            var id=$(this).attr('id');
            // if the parent unchecked uncheck children
            $(this).parent().find('li input[type="checkbox"][id^="'+id+'"]').prop('checked', false);            
        }
    });
    $('label').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').trigger('click');
    });
});

$('#get').click(function(){
    $('#root input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){        
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        //get last checked childern
        if($(this).parent().not(':has(ul)').size()>0)
        {
            var name=$(this).attr('name');
            var value=$(this).val();            

            alert(name+':'+value);
        }
    })
})
```